# Shortcodes of Gallery Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm Currently using the Wordpress Gallery Plugin, and it is working fine, but I want to List all the Galleries already created on one page.

The Gallery Plugin Shortcodes work fine, here is an example of one: `[print_gllr id=43 display=short]`

I can display that Shortcode using this: `<?php echo do_shortcode('[print_gllr id=43 display=short]'); ?>`

But, isn't there a way to Display all Shortcodes of print_gllr with display=short?

Thanks a lot in Advace.

Comment: I just want to make sure I have the right idea: You want to be able to display each and every gallery you've ever made on a single page?

Comment: Yes, thanks for you comment! But I have already solved that question. You can see my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
<?php 
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'gallery' );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
   <?php echo do_shortcode('[print_gllr id='.get_the_ID().' display=short]'); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

It Will create a Loop with all the Galleries covers, so you can use it in a Page, to display'em All.

Comment: Glad you got it all sorted. On a side note, thank you for using WP_Query. query_posts makes my retinas burn.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it will be Useful for someone.